# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Tags: python, pandas

Code is below

I am using python version 3.5

```
# train a random forest classifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 42)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# show feature importance
feature_importances_df = pd.DataFrame({"feature": features, "importance": rf.feature_importances_}).sort_values("importance", ascending = False)
feature_importances_df.head(20)
```

tried

```
feature_importances = {"feature": features, "importance": rf.feature_importances_}.sort_values("importance", ascending = False)
feature_importances_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(feature_importances, orient='index')
```

I was trying to learn sentimental analysis. got stuck with error

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sort_values'`

Comment: move the `sort_values` to after the `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python 3.6.8 and pandas 0.25.1

try this

```
dictionary = {"a":[2,3,1,4],"b":["a","f","g","z"]}
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
dataFrame.sort_values('a',ascending=False,inplace = True)
dataFrame.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This will print

```
   a  b
0  4  z
1  3  f
2  2  a
3  1  g
```

Hope that it helps!